# For a given local field $k$ and its finite extension $k'$, is it possible to look for $k_0/k$ subextension of $k/k$ s.t. $e(k_0/k)=e(k'/k)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a local field and $k'$ finite extension of $k$. Consider all non-trivial subextensions of $k'/k$.

$\textbf{Q1:}$ I am looking for $k_0/k$ as subextension of $k'/k$ s.t. $e(k_0/k)=[k_0:k]$ and $k_0\neq k$. Is such $k_0$ always going to exist in the ambient extension $k'/k$? My first naive thought was maximal totally ramified extension which may not exists in the comment below which shows ramified extensions are not closed under field composition.

$\textbf{Q2:}$ Suppose $e(k'/k)>1$. I am looking for $k_0/k$ as subextension of $k'/k$ s.t. $e(k_0/k)=e(k'/k)$.(Note that normally, one will get $e(k_0/k)=1$ and deduce $e(k'/k_0)=e(k'/k)$.) Do I always have such a subextension available?

Comment: I believe that‘s only possible when $k‘/k$ is totally ramified itself.

Comment: @LukasKofler When totally ramified, it follows easily every subextension is totally ramified. What is the reason to expect that there is no totally ramified extension in general?

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible to look"?  It's always possible to look for things. Tell us if there are some *properties* you want to be satisfied, e.g., $k_0/k$ is a maximal totally ramified subextension (containing all other totally ramified intermediate extensions).

Comment: There need not be a maximal totally ramified extension.  For instance, consider $k = \mathbf Q_5$ and $k' = k(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{10})$.  Then $[k':k] = 4$ and the only intermediate extensions (of degree $2$) are $k(\sqrt{5})$, $k(\sqrt{10})$, and $k(\sqrt{2})$.  The first two intermediate extensions are each totally ramified over $k$, the third is unratified over $k$, and there is no totally ramified intermediate extension containing *all* the others.

Comment: @KCd I see. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are asking if there is *some* intermediate extension $k'/k_0/k$ such that $k_0/k$ is totally ramified and $e(k_0/k) = e(k'/k)$.  Please rewrite your question so it is asking something more precise than the current vague "Is it possible to look for" question.

Comment: @KCd I have re-written the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of local fields. Even if $L/K$ is ramified, it is certainly possible for there to be *no* non-trivial intermediate extension $E/K$ contained in $L/K$ such that $E/K$ is totally ramified. Here is an example. Let $p = 5$, and $K = \mathbf{Q}_5$, so $K$ contains a $4$th root of unity. Note that $2$ is not a quadratic residue, so $\mathbf{Q}_5(\sqrt{2})$ is the non-trivial unramified extension of $K$. Now let

$$L = \mathbf{Q}_p(\sqrt[4]{2 \cdot 5^2}).$$

The field $L$ is Galois over $K$ with $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K) = \mathbf{Z}/4\mathbf{Z}$. By Galois theory, there is a unique intermediate subfield, which is $E$. Note, however, that $E/K$ is unramified, but $L/K$ is ramified, because $\sqrt[4]{2p^2}$ has valuation $1/2$. So the answer to both of your questions is negative.

There is, however, somewhat of a fix if one assumes that $L/K$ is Galois *and* is allowed to take the compositum of $L$ and $K$ with some finite unramified extension. Namely:

**Claim:** Let $L/K$ be a finite Galois extension with ramification degree $e$. There exists an extension $E/K$ with the following properties:

1. $e(E/K) = e(L/K)$
2. $E/K$ is totally ramified, so $[E:K] = e(E/K)$.
3. $E$ may not be contained in $L$, but it is contained in $L' = L.K'$, the compositum of $L$ with an unramified extension $K'/K$.

In the example above, one can take $E  = \mathbf{Q}_5(\sqrt{5})$, and then take  $K' = \mathbf{Q}_5(\sqrt[4]{2})$, so

$$L' = \mathbf{Q}_5(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{50}) = \mathbf{Q}_5(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[4]{25}) = \mathbf{Q}_5(\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt{5}) \supset E.$$

**Proof:** Note that there is an exact sequence:

$$0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(L/K) \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(l/k) \rightarrow 0,$$

where $l$ is the residue field of $L$. To find an extension which is totally ramified, one wants the Frobenius element to fix the field. So one can take a lift $\phi$ of Frobenius and then take the fixed field. The problem is that some power of $\phi$ may be a  non-trivial element of $I$, and then the fixed field has a smaller ramification degree than desired. This can be avoided exactly when
there is a splitting of the exact sequence above. However, this sequence need not split in general. (See the original example where the flanking groups had order $2$ and the middle was cyclic of order $2$).

Suppose that $K^{ur}$ is the maximal unramified extension of $K$. Then there is also an exact sequence:

$$0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(L.K^{ur}/K)
\rightarrow \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/k) \rightarrow 0,$$

and this does split, because the RHS is $\widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$ which automatically admits a section. Let $\phi$ be the image of this section, and then let $E$ be the fixed field of (the closure of) $\phi$. Then $E$ has the required properties. (Since $\langle \phi \rangle$ is disjoint from $I$, the field $E$ has $e(E/K) = |I| = e(L/K)$, and since Frobenius acts trivially, $f(E/K) = 1$.)

---

If $L/K$ is not Galois, then the situation is even worse, there need not exist any such $E$. Let $K = \mathbf{Q}_2$, and let

$$L = \mathbf{Q}_2[x]/(x^4 + 2x^2 + 4x + 4).$$

Note that $L$ has degree $4$, and $e(L/K) = 2$, so $L$ contains an unramified quadratic extension,
but if $M$ is the Galois closure then $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K) = D_8$ with $I = (\mathbf{Z}/2)^2$. If any $E$ existed, then $E/\mathbf{Q}_2$ would have degree $2$, and so must be one of $6$ possible ramified extensions. But one can check that for all such $E$, the compositum of $E$ with $L$ is ramified over $L$, which rules out $E$ being a subfield of $L.K'$ for some unramified $K'/\mathbf{Q}_2$.